# Code review: what will be best possible way for the solution of this java program?

Tags: java

Consider a list `Ls` of `URL`s of all web pages within a given site i.e. all URLs in the list have the same domain prefix (for example, `http://www.fancysite.com`).  The rest of each URL after stripping the prefix is a sequence of strings separated by a `/b`  i.e. of the form `/abc/xyz/pqs/.../lmn.html.`
 
The problem to be solved is to compute the number of URLs in `Ls` at a given level. A level is counted by the number of slashes (i.e. `/b`  characters) in the URL after stripping the common domain prefix. For example, `http://www.fancysite.com`  is at `level 0`, `http://www.fancysite.com/xyz/xyz.html`  is at `level 2`, and so on. You may assume that the URLs in `Ls` are unique (i.e. `Ls` has no duplicates).

For above question, I have written the following code below:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();

for(String url : ls){
    String [] parts = url.split(https://www.fancysite.com);
    int count=0;

    for(int i=0; i<=parts[1].length(); i++){
        if(parts[1].charAt(i)== “/“){
            count++;
        }
        S.O.P(“Level of this particular url is”+ count;
    }
}
```

Any comment / update / approach will be appreciated

Comment: Post this at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: `A level is counted by the number of slashes` A path can end in a slash, but if there's nothing after the slash I don't think that should increase the "level" of the path count.

Comment: @markspace seems like the path will finish with the .html everytime.. hence counting only the required slashes in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner:

```
final String URL = "https://example.com/one/two";
long level = URL.chars().filter(ch -> ch == '/').count() - 2;
```

Here, we count the number of slashes `/` in the String and then subtract 2 for the initial number of slashes after *https*.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
        ls.add("https://example.com");
        ls.add("https://example.com/one");
        ls.add("https://example.com/two");
        ls.add("https://example.com/one/three");
        ls.add("https://example.com/one/one");
        ls.add("https://example.com/one/two");


        Map<Integer, List<URL>> levelToUrls = new HashMap<>();

        for(String urlRaw : ls){
            URL url = new URL(urlRaw);
            String path = url.getPath();
            String[] splitedPath = path.split("/");
            levelToUrls.computeIfAbsent(splitedPath.length - 1, integer -> new LinkedList<>()).add(url);
        }

        levelToUrls.forEach((integer, urls) -> System.out.println("Level " + integer + " How many : " + urls.size()));
    }
```

This outputs :

```
Level 0 How many : 1
Level 1 How many : 2
Level 2 How many : 3
```

Basically I am using a map to store the list of urls mapped to corresponding level, however `Map<Integer, Integer>` would be also sufficient if you do not want to have acces to urls by level.

Same result using Java 8 streams :

```
Map<Integer, Long> levelToUrlCount = ls.stream()
                .map(s -> s.split("/").length - 3)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));


levelToUrlCount.forEach((level, howMany) -> System.out.println("Level " + level + " How many : " + howMany));
```

Comment: Your approch seems good but i need result as every url with respective level kindda output!

Comment: You have data it in the map so you can do anything with the data stored in the map. Now this map maps level to List of urls.